# Errors while using Jsdoc and better-docs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, documentation, jsdoc

I'm trying to use jsdoc in order to generate documentation for my TypeScript project. I run the following command:

`jsdoc -c jsdoc.json src/entity/entity.service.ts -t ./node_modules/better-docs`

But on my service, I get this error:

`Unexpected token, expected ","`

On my controller, an other one:

`Unexpected reserved word 'private'.`

I don't understand what is happening, as my code is running without any errors nor warnings and I use **eslint-plugin-jsdoc** in order to make sure that my Jsdoc is correct.

Here is a part of my code if you want to make sure everything's okay.

entity.service.ts

```
  /**
   * My description
   *
   * @author My name
   * @async
   * @param {Buffer} markdown - My description.
   * @returns {Buffer} - My description.
   * @see [md-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-to-pdf)
   */
  async convertMd2Pdf(markdown: Buffer): Promise<Buffer> {
    try {
      const pdf = await mdToPdf({ content: markdown.toString('utf-8') });
      return pdf.content;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new BadRequestException(err);
    }
  }
```

entity.controller.ts

```
/**
 * Controller of the entity md2pdf.
 *
 * @author My name
 * @typedef {Md2pdfController}
 * @class md2pdfService
 */
@Controller()
export class Md2pdfController {
  constructor(private readonly md2pdfService: Md2pdfService) {}
  [...]
}
```

I think Jsdoc is not the best to use with TypeScript. If you have any other recommandations, I would love to check them!

Answer (score 0):

I had use "clean-jsdoc-theme" for documentation.

I had converted ".ts" files into ".js" and ".d.ts", you can see in jsdoc.json file below, I had passed ".js" files in "include: []". As "jsdoc" needs ".js" files for creating the documentation.

jsdoc.json

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": [
      "dist/User/index.js",
      "dist/Organization/index.js",
      "dist/Application/index.js",
      "dist/EndDevice/index.js",
      "dist/Gateway/index.js",
      "dist/Interfaces/Doc Common/docApp.interface.js",
      "dist/Interfaces/Doc Common/docEndDevice.interface.js"
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "template": "node_modules/clean-jsdoc-theme",
    "readme": "./readme/readme.md",
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs/",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "verbose": true,
    "theme_opts": {
      "default_theme": "dark",
      "search": true,
      "title": "Test",
      "homepageTitle": "Docs"
    }
  },
  "markdown": {
    "hardwrap": false,
    "idInHeadings": true
  }
}
```

package.json:-

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json",
  }
```

In my case it is working perfectly. May it helps you.

If you don't want to use "jsdoc", you can go for "compdoc" [Compdoc npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@compodoc/compodoc).